# How to plot a constant function Probability Density Function

Tags: r

I have a function like this:

```
f(X) = 1/b-a  where a = 5% and b =15% and X = rate of return.
```

I would like to plot the probability density function of this.

What I have tried:

I know I need to use `dname()` for density or probability function but I do not know the name to pass to this.

Comment: `curve` accepts an expression, like a function. What's 5% and 15%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roman suggests, how about the following:

```
curve(dunif(x, min = 5, max = 15),0,20,n=101,xlab='Expected Return',ylab='Density')
```